# Is there a way to see outdated modules with private repo?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I am trying to see all my outdated versions of modules from in package.json using `npm outdated`.
But when I do `npm outdated` its throwing error as I am using few private npm modules. Is there a way to check only the public modules excluding the private?

```
npm outdated
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @scope/private@latest
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/subkundu/.npm/_logs/2019-03-04T18_02_24_747Z-debug.log
```